# react native: background of Searchbar (react-native-paper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to change the background of the Searchbar of the react-native-paper library?

```
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

           <Searchbar
            placeholder='search'
            onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
            inputStyle={styles.searchInput}
            value={searchQuery}
          />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can change it by adding style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}. Instead of red, you can give any color hex code.

```
<Searchbar
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
      value={searchQuery}
      style={{backgroundColor: '#800080'}}
    />
```

Comment: And how do I change the color of the placeholder and the icon of the magnifying glass inside?

Comment: You can add placeholderTextColor='#FFFFFF' for changing the color of the placeholder, but not sure about the magnifying glass

Comment: You understood what I meant with the magnifying glass icon in the placeholder, right?